# Memory overflow with multidimensional arrays of string in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, pebble-watch

I'm trying to use locale settings on a watch application. In order to do that, I first store the `locale` string in a variable with the following definition:

```
static char locale[] = "en_US";
```

I have a multidimensional array containing "packages" for each language. Here is a sample definition:

```
static const char *locale_packages[][2][12] = {
    {{"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"}, { "Jan", "Febr", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"}},         // EN = 0
    {{"Dim", "Lun", "Mar", "Mer", "Jeu", "Ven", "Sam"}, { "Janv", "Fevr", "Mars", "Avr", "Mai", "Juin", "Juil", "Aout", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"}}   // FR = 1
};
```

I also define arrays that will store the date strings for my language. Their definition is as follow:

```
static char *day_of_week[7];
static char *month_of_year[12];
```

My idea behind that was: if the locale is `fr_FR`, and I want to display the translation of *Wednesday* in French, then I just use `day_of_week[3]`.

Finally, I use this function

```
static void load_locale(char *locale_string, char *day_var[], char *month_var[]) {
  static int locale_int;
  locale_int = locale_number(locale_string); 
  // locale_number returns the array position of my locale. 
  // For instance, locale_number("en_US") will return '0'
  static char *selected_locale[2][12];
  memcpy(selected_locale, locale_packages[locale_int], sizeof locale_packages[locale_int]);
  memcpy(day_var, selected_locale[0], sizeof selected_locale[0]);
  memcpy(month_var, selected_locale[1], sizeof selected_locale[1]);
}
```

And finally, I just run:

```
load_locale(locale, day_of_week, month_of_year);
```

However, despite the compilation being successful, the app crashes right after 'loading locales'. I was able to return a few values in the log, and every test I tried worked, so that means my function 'does what it should', but there seems to be a memory overflow or something like that.

Does someone see the mistake I made? I'm not very experienced in C and that's the first time I use multidimensional arrays.

Comment: If you really meant `static char *selected_locale[2][12]` and not just `static char selected_locale[2][12]` you should allocate the space for the buffer.

Comment: Can you provide console output?

Comment: It's hard to answer a question when it has bits and pieces of code. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @RSahu Sorry, I thought explaining per blocks might be a more efficient explanation.

Comment: @Gaskoin Unfortunately, Pebble Watches use a custom compiler. The only relevant line in the output is a Traceback that returns the wrong line.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Shouldn't the compiler do that automatically? I'll try right now.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError array declarations do allocate space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with this code:

```
memcpy(day_var, selected_locale[0], sizeof selected_locale[0]);
```

If you are actually passing in `static char *day_of_week[7];` as the parameter for `day_var`,  then you cause a buffer overflow because `selected_locale[0]` has 12 entries. (7 pointers to strings and 5 null pointers).

To fix this you will need to adjust how much you are memcpy'ing.

---

NB.  `selected_locale` is redundant. You could just copy directly from `locale_packages[locale_int][0]` into `day_var` and so on.

If you do keep it then it doesn't need to be static, and it should have `const` next to the `char`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that. I changed the code to include an allocation for `day_of_week`, like this: `*day_of_week = malloc(sizeof(locale_packages[locale_int][0]));`. However, after logging `"%i/%i bytes",sizeof(day_of_week), sizeof(locale_packages[locale_int][0]`, I get this: `28/48 bytes`. Why is `malloc` not properly working here?

Comment: @LaX the array was fine without malloc, it would unnecessarily complicate things to try and introduce malloc. The 500 guy doesn't know what he is talking about.  Where did you write `*day_of_week = ...` ?  If that is in the code that is calling `load_locale` then you have (unnecessarily) malloc'd space for one of the 7 pointers in `day_of_week` to point to (remember that `*p` means `p[0]`).  `sizeof(day_of_week)` is 28 because it is an array of 7 pointers and each pointer is 4 bytes on your system. What were you expecting? `sizeof` cannot tell you how much space has been malloc'd.

Comment: Sorry, I was outside the `load_locale` function testing this and I forgot to mention it. I'll just use `sizeof(day_var)` inside the `load_locale`'s `memcpy`. By the way, I think malloc wasn't allocating enough bytes because I kept `static char *day_of_week[7];` in the definition, but I'm not using it anymore.

Comment: @LaX just stick to the original code you posted in your question and change the `memcpy` to copy 7 days instead of 12

Comment: You **may** not need all these memcpy, just declare 
`static const char **day_of_week; 
static const char **month_of_year;` 
and assign them directly with respectidly 
`locale_packages[locale_int][0];
locale_packages[locale_int][1];`

Comment: @JoëlHecht Strange… Last time I tried, I had `error: invalid initializer` stopping the compiler. That's why I ended up using `memcpy`. Trying again now it works fine. Maybe I forgot one `*`. The only issue with this solution is that I have to find a way to initialize `locale_int` before the `**day_of_week` and `**month_of_year` declaration.

Comment: @LaX in Joël's suggestion, make `load_locale` accept triple pointers ; and the calling code will pass the addresses of two double pointers. Then `load_locale` sets the int and outputs the two pointers. (`locale_int` does not need to be static)

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to get day and month names in your locale language then you can use:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);

char day[10], month[10];
strftime(day, sizeof(day), "%a", time);
strftime(month, sizeof(month), "%b", time);
```

(where time is a `struct tm`).

Note:

- See the [translating your apps guide](http://developer.getpebble.com/guides/publishing-tools/i18n-guide/#effect-of-setting-a-locale) for reference.
- `%a` gives you a abbreviated weekday name; %A the full weekday name. Same thing for `%b`/`%B` and month names. (see [`strftime()` format reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/)).

If you really want to have your own list of translations the same guide also offers [a clean solution to that](http://developer.getpebble.com/guides/publishing-tools/i18n-guide/#using-locale-dictionaries).

Comment: I figured that out last night. That made me angry and I went straight to bed. I'll take that path instead and dump everything I made, much better. Thanks!